# Can I specify a path to Python.h for sip-4.18.1 when running 'make' command?

Tags: python, linux, rhel, rhel7, python-sip

I am trying to configure `sip-4.18.1` on `RHEL 7`. I have `downloaded/installed/configured Python3.5.2`.

When I run 'make' inside sip directory I get this error:

> gcc -c -pipe -fPIC -O2 -Wall -W -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o siplib.o siplib.c
>   siplib.c:20:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>    #include

Which I would understand to mean that there is `Python 2.7` at least downloaded to this machine, but it doesn't look to be configured.

Is there any way I can specify a path for sip to look for `Python.h` when running 'make'?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install python-dev and/or python3-dev

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```